# How to save video recording to documents directory with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have written this code to record video and would like to save the filePath to the documents directory, how can I do this?

```
func startRecording() {
    var currentDateTime = NSDate()
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"
    var recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime) + ".mp4"
    var pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        videoRecorder = UIImagePickerController()
        videoRecorder.delegate = self
        videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
        videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 3600.0
        videoRecorder.startVideoCapture()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this before, you can use NSFileHandle to do this

NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: filePath, error: nil)

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to ask if there is a way I can connect that filePath to the video recording?

Comment: Normally, you can use ALAssetsLibrary to get the video file asset when you done recording.